# Check if all sql queries ran without error

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to shorten my code and I thought using array is the best way.

This code is made pretty much of many different queries (mysqli) like this:

```
$a = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$b = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$c = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$d = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$e = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$f = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$g = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$h = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$i = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$j = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$k = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
```

To check if this queries are correctly executed I do this (as they will return true/false):

```
if($a && $b && $c && $d && $e && $f && $g && $h && $i && $j && $k){
    //action    
}
```

But every time I've to add a query I've to add it to the if statement and it gets so long I don't know if I included it or not...

So, now I'm thinking of doing this with arrays:

```
$a[0] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[1] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[2] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[3] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[4] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[5] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[6] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[7] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[8] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[9] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$a[10] = $this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");

if($a === true){
    //ok
}else{
    //notok;
}
```

But this code (if statement) doesn't work...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method would be to enable exceptions for mysqli (in the recent PHP versions they are enabled by default). For this add this line to your connection code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

And then run your queries as usual.

Any query that fails will throw an exception and thus you will be informed about error.

If you want to retract all previous queries in case of error, as though they were never executed, you can use a transaction (given exceptions enabled as shown above):

```
$this->db->begin_transaction();

$this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");
$this->db->query("DELETE * FROM ....");

$this->db->commit();
echo 'They are all ok.'
```

So you will see either 'They are all ok.' or the error message. In the latter case all queries will be rolled back.

In case such an error is not considered fatal, and your code can resume its execution despite the error, you can wrap the entire transaction in a `try..catch` block. In this case you must call `$this->db->rollback()` inside the `catch` block manually.

Comment: It is important to note that the asker's scripts do not short-circuit before executing all queries.  This answer is denying subsequent queries from being run as soon as one of them fails.  It is important to also note that neither the question's code nor this answer's code are bothering to see if there are any affected rows -- they are only checking if the queries executed without error.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it factually correct and closer to best practices. You may keep or rollback it

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think it would be just better if you add a new answer of your own and then downvote this one. Your edit is pretty much a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with an array, but you could also just put all the queries into a transaction and check whether committing them works:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

// put your queries here    

if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
    print("Transaction commit failed");
    exit();
}
```

This way, you also make sure all of your queries in the transaction are successful (which is what I assume you are trying to find out or handle). if the commit fails, none of the queries are executed at all (except for DDL changing statements).

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. commit doesn't check whether any queries failed. it will return false only if failed itself.

Answer (score -2):

Try using a foreach on your array...

```
$a[0] = true;
$a[1] = true;
$a[2] = true;
$a[3] = true;
$a[4] = true;
$a[5] = true;

$all_ok=true;
foreach($a as $a_ok)
{
  if(!($a_ok === true))
  {
    $all_ok=false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of indexing the actual database query results, you should index the queries themselves. Execute each query, and if it is false, then we know that they are not all true.

For example.

```
$queries = array(
    'SELECT * FROM ...',
    'SELECT * FROM ...',
    'SELECT * FROM ...',
    'SELECT * FROM ...'
);

// iterate through the queries
foreach ($queries as $query) {
    // execute this query and check the result to be false
    if (!$this->db->query($query)) {
        // handle "not ok" case
        // ...

        // exit the function
        return;
    }
}

// they were all true, so we can handle the "ok" case
// ...
```

Answer (score -2):

A more straightforward solution than what is presented:

```
$all_true = !in_array(false, $a);
```

This will also be faster (the iterations will be done in the PHP engine vs. your code) and if you want to ensure that the array only contains booleans and you're using a compatible version of PHP:

```
$all_true = (fn(bool ...$arr) => !in_array(false, $a))(...$a);
```

Comment: Do you mean `$a` or `$arr` in your custom callback?  I don't see `$arr` being used after it is declared.